# problems opening and editing Access 2003 with Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

Our company recently upgraded our systems to include Access 2010. All of our database is Access 2003. From time to time, I open our standard database and our regular forms appear. Some forms are available for editing and updating while some are locked and not available. How can I unlock all of the forms within the database?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether the same forms are always locked, or whether any given form is sometimes locked and sometimes available. However, using split databases would prevent this problem: each person gets a separate copy of the UI - a "front-end" database - but they all point to the same data tables - a "back-end" database.

More info about splitting: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-an-access-database-HA010342026.aspx

It also isn't clear whether there's a reason you want to keep your databases in .mdb format. Unless you are using a feature that is no longer supported - or some users don't have Access 2010 - consider upgrading your database files to the .accdb format - you'll get some cool new features, such as control layouts, attachment fields, built-in date pickers, etc.

Overview of new features in 2007/2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-s-new-in-microsoft-access-HA010342117.aspx

Allen Browne's overview of differences between 2003 and 2007: http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html

Features deprecated in 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-access-2010-HA101806473.aspx